# MySQL - SELECT duplicando?

Tags: mysql

Alguém sabe me dizer por que está duplicando os `SELECT`?

```
CREATE TABLE tb_grupos(
  id_tbl_grupos int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  id_grupo int(50) NOT NULL,
  hostname_grupo varchar(50) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE tb_hosts (
  id_tbl_host int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  id_host int(50) NOT NULL,
  hostname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  fk_hostname_grupo int(3) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (fk_hostname_grupo) REFERENCES tb_grupos(id_tbl_grupos));

  CREATE TABLE tb_monitoramento (
  id_tbl_monitoramento int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  problemas varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  tempo int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  fk2_hostname_grupo int(3) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (fk2_hostname_grupo) REFERENCES tb_grupos(id_tbl_grupos));
CREATE TABLE tb_eventos (
  id_tbl_eventos int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  id_evento int(50) NOT NULL,
  eventos varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  tempo int(50) NOT NULL,
  trigger_or_network int(3) NOT NULL,
  ok_or_problema_or_desconhecido int(3) NOT NULL,
  fk3_hostname_grupo int(3) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (fk3_hostname_grupo) REFERENCES tb_grupos(id_tbl_grupos));

  insert into tb_grupos values("0","15","HOUSE"); 
  insert into tb_hosts values("0","10087","HOUSE - MICRO", 1);
  insert into tb_grupos values("0","16","CLIENTE"); 
  insert into tb_hosts values("0","10088","CLIENTE - DIRETORIA", 1); 

  insert into tb_monitoramento values("0","MEMÓRIA EM ALTO CONSUMO EM HOUSE - MICRO","158909809",1); 
  insert into tb_monitoramento values("0","ERRO DE DISCO CLIENTE - DIRETORIA","158909856",1);

  SELECT
   tb_grupos.hostname_grupo,
   tb_monitoramento.problemas,
   tb_monitoramento.tempo
  FROM
   tb_grupos
  LEFT JOIN
   tb_monitoramento ON tb_grupos.id_tbl_grupos = tb_monitoramento.fk2_hostname_grupo
  WHERE
   tb_grupos.hostname_grupo = 'HOUSE'
```

Saída:

```
HOUSE   MEMÓRIA EM ALTO CONSUMO EM HOUSE - MICRO    158909809
HOUSE   ERRO DE DISCO CLIENTE - DIRETORIA   158909856
```

Comment: Aparentemente você está apontando para o mesmo id de grupo em seus inserts, ambos estão setados como 1.

Comment: Poste a listagem de suas tabelas para facilitar a análise.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Em sua tabela `tb_monitoramento` ambos os registros estão com o mesmo fk2_hostname_grupo.

Se você quer usar a query já pra agrupar, use `group_concat`, ou `group_by`.

Comment: Obrigado, vou passar no algoritmo para incrementar +1 no ultimo valor assim mantendo a tabela relacionada!